# Adding user to xmpp room

Tags: ios, xmpp

Hello I know there is alot question regarding this but still i could not figure out what can be the problem. I have sucessfully created group using following code.

```
- (void)createGroup
{

iXmppEngine.userID = @"lahore123@hassan.local";
    iXmppEngine.userPass = @"password123";
    self.rosterstorage  =[[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];

    XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:self.rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test@conference.hassan.local"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];


    [xmppRoom activate:[[self iXmppEngine]xmppStream]];

    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"Dev iphone" history:nil];



    [[[self iXmppEngine] xmppStream]  addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [self performSelector:@selector(joinRoom) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];

}
```

And For adding user i used following code. I have called this function with delay of 5s so room can be created succesfully before adding users.

```
- (void)joinRoom
{
    self.iXmppEngine.userID = @"lahore@hassan.local";

//    self.rosterstorage = [[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
    XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:self.rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test@conference.hassan.local"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoom activate:[[self iXmppEngine] xmppStream]];
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"lahore" history:nil];
    [xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
    [xmppRoom configureRoomUsingOptions:nil];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:[self iXmppEngine] delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];


}
```

What i am doing wrong couldnt find.

Answer (score 0):

Creating and Joining (Already Created Room or Accepting Invitation To Join Room) Rooms are two differnet scenarios.

//   CONFERENCE_ROOM_SERVER is the domain name for MUC

For Creating Group Do This Way:

```
- (void)createChatRoom:(NSString *) newRoomName
{
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", newRoomName, CONFERENCE_ROOM_SERVER]];

    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomMemoryStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];

    xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc]
                initWithRoomStorage:roomMemoryStorage
                jid:roomJID
                dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    [xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"Your Nick Name" history:nil];

}
```

You will get the response after the group has been created successfully in this delegate:

```
- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender
```

Now Invite Users Here This Way:

```
[sender inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:inviteUserJID] withMessage:@"Any Message"];
```